# Onload clear all text fields jquery js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I clear all text fields on a page, deselect buttons etc? I simply want to refresh the page when it loads.. like holding Shift + Refresh?

Comment: You want to refresh the page when it loads? You know that will make an infinite reload loop, don't you? Do you want to just clear all input's values instead?

Comment: yes, sorry. just clear all input values on the page.

Answer (score 6):

Give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type!="button"][type!="submit"], select, textarea')
         .val('')
         .blur();
});
```

Clearing the values on buttons and submit buttons will give them a blank label, hence the more complex selector.

Comment: Your selector will still match buttons, since `input[type!='submit']` matches buttons (and vice versa); it should probably be `input[type!='button'][type!='submit']`

Answer (score 4):

If all elements are in form,

then use `document.getElementById('your-form-id').reset();`

or `$('#your-form-id')[0].reset();`

Otherwise:

```
$('input, textarea').each(function() {
    this.value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a more elegant solution than this, but to simply clear the values you can do this:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
$('select').each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).find('option').val());
};
```